# MongoDB Select documents by the value of a specific field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, get

MongoDB - userModel (simplified)

```
  {
    _id: "exampleid1",
    name: "examplename1",
    following: [
      {
        _id: "exampleid2",
        name: "examplename2"
      },
      {
        _id: "exampleid3",
        name: "examplename3"
      }
    ],
    followers: [
      {
        _id: "exampleid4",
        name: "examplename4"
      },
      {
        _id: "exampleid5",
        name: "examplename5"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Hey,
I'm building a social media platform and I need to get from the database only the users that I follow.

I tried the query below, but gives me nothing:

```
User.find( { "followers": { _id: "exampleid1"} } )
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: An array of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to divide the document selection (`{_id: "exampleid1"}`) from the projection (`{followers: 1, _id: 0}`):

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: "exampleid1"
},
{
  followers: 1,
  _id: 0
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IqSPmM1voP1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very well explained and a nice example in the playground What if I would like to get the entire documents of these users, because here in "followers" are only the headers of these users, and I need to get the entire users based on these headers. As with the User. find() but only with users from the following or followers list.

Comment: You can use an aggregation pipeline with `$lookup` to get them on the same query, or use another query based on the results of this query